# Unable to access authorization.user._id after refreshing once

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meanjs

I have developed a NodeJS app (MeanJS) with Yo generator.
I think there is an issue with the authentication module.

I am trying to access the `authentication.user._id` value in the HTML page using `{{authentication.user._id}}` and it works fine for the first time when the user logs in. But as soon as the user refreshes the page, this particular value is gone. All other values in `authentication.user` are still there, but the `"_id"` value is gone until I re-login. Why is this happening?

I want the `"_id"` value to persist even after refreshing the page, since the user is still logged in and it is the same session. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `core.server.controller.js` file you need to add this line of code:

```
_id:validator.escape(req.user._id)
```

At the begining of the `safeUserObject` in `renderIndex` function. Save it, restart the server and try again.

Comment: You Sir, are a genius! Thank you so much!